# Trying to ForceIndex MYsql

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT fldjobitemid, fldstatus, tblbulkreportjobitems.fldparticipantid, CONCAT(fldFirstName, ' ', fldLastName) as full_name FROM tblbulkreportjobitems FORCE INDEX (fldparticipantid) JOIN tblparticipant ON tblparticipant.fldParticipantId = tblbulkreportjobitems.fldparticipantid WHERE fldjobid = 9 ORDER BY fldjobitemid
    -> ;
+----+-------------+-----------------------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                 | type   | possible_keys            | key     | key_len | ref                                                  | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tblbulkreportjobitems | ALL    | fldparticipantid         | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                                 |  869 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tblparticipant        | eq_ref | PRIMARY,fldParticipantId | PRIMARY | 4       | medicus_devel.tblbulkreportjobitems.fldparticipantid |    1 | Using where                 |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Why is it using a filesort still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL Query Optimizer will always overrule your choice of index if the number of keys is 5% of the number of rows in the table.

Run these queries please:

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblbulkreportjobitems;
I guess this should be 869 (from the explain plan)

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblbulkreportjobitems WHERE fldjobid  = 9;

SELECT COUNT(1),fldjobid FROM tblbulkreportjobitems GROUP BY fldjobid WITH ROLLUP;

SELECT COUNT(1),fldjobid FROM tblbulkreportjobitems GROUP BY fldjobid WITH ROLLUP;

You will see which rows that appear more than 5% of the total rows. In that case, the MySQL Query Optimizer will choose a full table scan over using a lopsided index.

If you had fldparticipantid in the WHERE clause, then you will get a different result.